# Should we close 6417?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

The Q&A page has a question »[Why does my Tor talk to activate.adobe.com?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/6417/88)«. [Sebastian](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/6883/sebastian) tried to answer it and in the comments it turned out that the user has a [cracked version of Adobe](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/why-does-my-tor-talk-to-activate-adobe-com#comment6327_6418). I think that neither the question nor the answer are of interest of the general public and would vote to close the question. However before I'd like to know your opinion about it.

Comment: i think it can be closed.

Comment: I'm in agreement.

Comment: Sure, please close this question. I am so sorry for the accident.